# Why this regex ignores just vowels ?

Tags: regex, expression

My questions is what logic this regex implements so that it not select vowels from the words ?

Here is the Regular Expression :

```
^[AEIOUaeiou]+|[AEIOUaeiou]+$|[^AEIOUaeiou]
```

**Sample Text** :

> could not but sigh over it, and wish for impossible things,till her father >awoke, and made it necessary to be cheerful.His spirits required support.  He >was a nervous man, easily depressed;fond of every body that he was used to, >and hating to part with them;hating change of every kind.  Matrimony, as the >origin of change,

**Regex Result** :

> cld nt bt sgh vr t, nd wsh fr mpssbl thngs,tll hr fthr wk, nd md t ncssry t b >chrfl.Hs sprts rqrd spprt.  H ws  nrvs mn, sly dprssd;fnd f vry bdy tht h >ws sd t, nd htng t prt wth thm;htng chng f vry knd.  Mtrmny, s th rgn f chng

My focus is on "What part of above REGEX negates the selection of noun"

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Would you be able to rephrase it?

Comment: Wouldnt it be beautiful if there were an website where you can input regexes and text and they highlight every match AND explaint the regex for you? Wait .... http://www.regexr.com .... and about a dozend more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not negate the selection of a noun, but rather simply matches based on **vowels**.

Specifically, the regex runs an `OR` (`|`) conditional, checking against any of the three parts:

- `^[AEIOUaeiou]+` - Checks whether the string **starts** with one or more vowels
- `[AEIOUaeiou]+$` - Checks whether the string **ends** with one or more vowels
- `[^AEIOUaeiou]` - Checks whether the string contains something that is **not** a vowel

It is basically saying that it will return a match if the string contains a vowel at the start or at the end... and will also return a match if the string contains anything **other** than a vowel (including special characters).

Comment: shouldnt `[^abc]` look for any 1 character that is neither a nor b nor c?

Comment: Correct; I misinterpreted that for a second. Whoops! I've corrected that now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches:

```
^                     Start of line
[AEIOUaeiou]+         1-n times any of the characters in []

|               OR

[AEIOUaeiou]+         1-n times any on the characters in []
$                     End of line

|               OR

[^AEIOUaeiou]         1 occurence of not any of those in []
```

The regexr would be:  https://regexr.com/3lm0k

Essentially you get plenty of matches (385) for the last part and none for the first ones as your string starts with `c` and ends on `.`